# bootstrap4 drop down menu only work once when I click it

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have a dropdown in my webpage. But it shows the menu items only once. ie-It shows the menu items only when I click it for the first time. If I reload the page again then it work again. Following is the code I have written for the dropdown menu.

```
<!-- Dropdown -->
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Shop
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Shoes</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Handbags</a>
      </div>
    </li>
```

Thank you.

And this is my header code

```
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
<title>My title</title>
```

Comment: Your code is working fine, I have just added bootstrap CSS and js. Please see: https://codepen.io/aalokmali/pen/mYjqwK

Comment: Thank you for the help. May be I have done something wrong in the <head> part. So I added that to the question.

Comment: Try updating your CSS link to version 4.3.1, and removing the local reference to the Bootstrap JS (`<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`).

Comment: It corrupt my web page when I update to that version. I didn't think that they do this much changes in new versions.

Answer (score 1):

Add `role="button"` to your toggle link:

```html
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">Shop</a>
```

Also, make sure you have loaded the Bootstrap JS file in your code.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. But it didn't solved it. I have doubt whether there is an issue in my <head> part. So I added that to the question.